# Which platforms does the IOTA community use?

Tags: untagged

I've seen different community platforms for IOTA around. Some are no longer in use.

What are the most important active platforms, and what's their focus?

Comment: Signup for the old iota forum has been broken for at least half a year... I don't have an account there either. The IOTA team is aware but they don't seem to care :-(

Comment: @mihi: thanks for the info ... so I guess it's reddit and stackexchange

Comment: @downvoters: It would be constructive if you left a comment as to why you downvoted.

Comment: and the new forum at https://forum.helloiota.com/

Comment: I see some value in the question, but should be edited to something like this: Which platforms does the IOTA community use? Then Slack, Reddit, Stackexchange and helloiota should be in the answer.

Comment: @teclis: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the question, you can go ahead and create the answer you proposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following platforms are used by the IOTA community

- Forum - https://forum.helloiota.com
- Reddit - https://www.reddit.com/r/Iota/
- IOTA on Stackexchange -  You are already here ;)
- Discord - https://discord.gg/fNGZXvh

The Forum and Reddit follow similar approaches: Asking questions and discussions.

Stackexchange is for Asking Questions and answering them to build a knowledge base about IOTA.

Discord <strike>The slack channel</strike> is for chatting directly with other IOTA users and the developers. The Slack Channel should no longer be used. Please use Discord instead.